# Codemirror Markdown level classes for headers

Tags: markdown, codemirror

using codemirror with markdown mode, how can I have individual classes for all headline levels.

e.g.

```
# headline <- class cm-header and cm-header-1
## headline level 2 <- class cm-header and cm-header-2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue, so changed my markdown.js file to look like this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/royletron/7317367). Once you change your mode for this it will append one of 3 different CSS styles as follows:

```
#Header 1 = .cm-header1
##Header 2 = .cm-header2
###Header 3 = .cm-header3
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Now [implemented in CodeMirror](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/commit/e327d2f) — markdown mode emits classes `cm-header1`..`cm-header6` in addition to `cm-header`.

See demo: http://codemirror.net/demo/variableheight.html

UPDATE: changed to `cm-header-1`..`cm-header-6` (with dash before number) [after 3.21](https://github.com/cben/CodeMirror/commit/f289321f6fd0a90cbafc304ea209b5dd5cada511).